# Adding /p:Platform="Any CPU" parameter forces the build in Debug configuration

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, roslyn

I run the following to build my solution (all projects in C#):

```
MSBuild.exe foo.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

It builds it in Debug configuration.  If i remove the reference to "Any CPU"

```
MSBuild.exe foo.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
```

the build is built in Release configuration.

Why is that?  Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Does it work if you drop the space (and quotes) from "Any CPU" to `AnyCPU`? Default csprojs usually have a property group looking like this: `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">`, so my thinking here is that it isn't matching the target platform and using the default build configuration.

Comment: @JonathonChase If I use AnyCPU, the build fails.  You might be right about the `PropertyGroup` piece - I just need to inspect a ton of projects in the solution.

Comment: Use `msbuild`'s  `/binaryLogger` and the [Download MSBuild Structured Log Viewer ](http://msbuildlog.com/) to diagnose this.

Comment: @AngryHacker, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT It was actually simpler than that.  In Solution/Configuration Manager, for the Release/AnyCPU setting, some projects were marked with Debug (not sure why - the solution is probably a decade old).  Setting it right fixed the problem.

Comment: @AngryHacker, Thanks for your reply. You can convert your comment to the answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.  While I was trying to find something complicated that's wrong with my solution (e.g. combing through a dozen .csproj files), the problem was embarrassingly simple.

In Solution/Configuration Manager, for the Release/AnyCPU setting, some projects were marked with Debug (not sure why - the solution is probably a decade old). Setting them to Release fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

> Adding /p:Platform=“Any CPU” parameter forces the build in Debug configuration

The output directory of the project is related to the property of `OutputPath` in the `PropertyGroup` in the project file `foo.csproj`.

According to your description, you may not have configured the target platform and `OutputPath` correctly in your project file, for example:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If we give the `<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>` for the Release configuration, then we will get the output in the Debug folder.

So, to resolve this issue, you need to check the property `OutputPath` in the project file, make sure it match the target platform.

Hope this helps.